# Make reactive changes on child on Parent events in VUE

Tags: vuejs2

I want to know what is the best way to change the child component from a Parent to an event. This is roughly what I want when some condition is not met and a button is pressed to the child will display. if the child is in this active state if the button is pressed again some animation will play on the child. If the condition is met the child automatically stops displaying.

Currently, I'm using prop syncs with an `activator` and a `de-activator` prop. when the button is pressed condition is not met the activator is set to `true` and the child displays its internal variable `active` is set to true and it emits the activator prop to false. When the `activator` prop turns true and `active` is true the animation plays. The same logic for the `de-activator` prop.

I want to know if there is a better more elegant way to do this.